# select top N rows from Datatable C# Windows form application

Tags: c#

I am using following code to select top 1000 rows from Datatable `dt_Customers` and update it with this selection.  Every thing is working fine.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt =  dt_Customers.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Take(1000).CopyToDataTable();
```

I am not sure this is the right way or not? Is there any other way to achieve this or I am going fine ?

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK this question is suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to instantiate new `DataTable` and assign it to `dt` variable. Also you can use `AsEnumerable()` extension:

```
DataTable dt = dt_Customers.AsEnumerable().Take(1000).CopyToDataTable();
```